# ctrl-shift-T not always opening type in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse

I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> keystroke in eclipse quite often, and in Neon it has stopped working some of the time.

I have been to the Window / Preferences / Open Type entry and deleted the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for JavaScript (though I don't think that should be necessary, it was recommended).

I have verified that this behavior happens in .txt and .xml windows in both Java and "Web" perspectives. It operates correctly if I have a Java file open in the editor, but I really want it to open when I'm looking at an XML file, since that often leads to wanting to look at Java source.

I also found a reference to going to one of the .metadata directories and deleting all the .index files and one other file (don't remember which now), then restarting eclipse. I did that, and it made no difference.

Is this a bug, so I should report it? Does anyone else see this behavior? Does anyone have another suggestion as a workaround? I'm quite keyboard-oriented, and this is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 1):

I've met the similar situation before, here is a solution,

left click the xml file---open with---xml editor

Using the eclipse's default xml editor may helps,I guess you've installed a plugin to open the xml file,so the problem may cause by the plugin,if you really want to use plugin to edit xml file,maybe you can try another plugin

Comment: I don't understand your answer at all. I would like to open a dialog which allows me to type in the name of a known class -- how does your "answer" do this?

Comment: my opinion is,when you use this way "left click the xml file---open with---xml editor" instead of using the plugin to open a xml file,the Ctrl+Shift+T shotcut may work,it may not work but you can hava a try,but first you should check the shotcut "Ctrl+Shift+T" not been use in the other way,hope it will help :-)

Comment: Any open XML files that I have came from double-clicking the file in project explorer. I have no plugin that I've installed for editing or opening XML files. If one came with the Neon installation, it should not interfere with this standard key assignment.